# Transaction request cannot include multiple operations on one item python

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

While using transact_write_item, I am facing below error:

An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the TransactWriteItems operation: Transaction request cannot include multiple operations on one item

Below is my code:

```
dynamodb.transact_write_items(
  TransactItems=[
   {
      "Update":{
         "Key":{
            "id":{
               "S":"8177-4cb6ca9ede00"
            }
         },
         "TableName":"user",
         "UpdateExpression":"SET #updated_at = :updated_at",
         "ExpressionAttributeNames":{
            "#updated_at":"updated_at"
         },
         "ExpressionAttributeValues":{
            ":updated_at":{
               "N":"1607588602447"
            }
         },
         "ConditionExpression":"attribute_exists(id)"
      }
   },
   {
      "Delete":{
         "Key":{
            "key":{
               "S":"00e4d492d86284ebf48a"
            }
         },
         "TableName":"user_name",
         "ConditionExpression":"#i = :i",
         "ExpressionAttributeNames":{
            "#i":"name"
         },
         "ExpressionAttributeValues":{
            ":i":{
               "S":"00e4d492d86284ebf48a"
            }
         }
      }
   },
   {
      "Put":{
         "Item":{
            "name":{
               "S":"700e4d492d86284ebf48a"
            }
         },
         "TableName":"user_name",
         "ConditionExpression":"#i <> :i",
         "ExpressionAttributeNames":{
            "#i":"name"
         },
         "ExpressionAttributeValues":{
            ":i":{
               "S":"700e4d492d86284ebf48a"
            }
         }
      }
   }
]
)
```

What am I missing? However if I perform a single action, it works.

Answer (score 1):

while they point to the same item, they use different exclusive conditions. (came here with the same problem, without a solution)

**Delete**

```
"ConditionExpression":"#i = :i",
```

**Put**

```
"ConditionExpression":"#i <> :i",
```

so i would consider it a bug, since the conditions should be checked before checking for the uniqueness of the keys. (the result would be only one of the items needs to be executed).

Answer (score 0):

The last two operations (Put & Delete) in `TransactItems` point to the same object:

```
 "Item": {
            "name":{
               "S":"700e4d492d86284ebf48a"
            }
         },
```