# C# AWS DynamoDB: Delete and Put item in same transaction

Tags: c#, transactions, amazon-dynamodb

In my API I work with tests. A test can contain questions, and a question can contain answers and images.

To update an item **in the simplest way** I delete test + questions + answers + images and then "Put" them again with new values in the same transaction.

Doing this I receive a `"Transaction request cannot include multiple operations on one item"` Exception.

`CreateTestAsync`:

```
public async Task<int> CreateTestAsync(TestDTO testDto, int saveMode)
{
    if (testDto.Questions == null) return Result.KO;

    try
    {
        //save test data
        //var table = Table.LoadTable(_client, Tables.Tests.TableName);
        transactionActions = new List<TransactWriteItem>();

        //delete items first
        if (saveMode == SaveMode.Update)
        {
            Delete delete;
            Dictionary<string, AttributeValue> key;

            if (testDto.Questions != null)
            {
                foreach (var question in testDto.Questions)
                {
                    if (question.Answers != null)
                    {
                        foreach (var answer in question.Answers)
                        {
                            //delete answer
                            delete = DeleteElementAsync1(Tables.Answers.TableName, Tables.Answers.Fields.Id, answer.Id);
                            transactionActions.Add(new TransactWriteItem { Delete = delete });
                        }
                    }

                    if (question.Images != null)
                    {
                        foreach (var image in question.Images)
                        {
                            //delete image
                            delete = DeleteElementAsync1(Tables.Images.TableName, Tables.Images.Fields.Id, image.Id);
                            transactionActions.Add(new TransactWriteItem { Delete = delete });
                            //delete image from S3
                        }
                    }
                    //delete question
                    delete = DeleteElementAsync1(Tables.Questions.TableName, Tables.Questions.Fields.Id, question.Id);
                    transactionActions.Add(new TransactWriteItem { Delete = delete });
                }
            }

            //delete test
            delete = DeleteElementAsync1(Tables.Tests.TableName, Tables.Tests.Fields.Id, testDto.Id);
            transactionActions.Add(new TransactWriteItem { Delete = delete });
        }

         //save test
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(testDto);
        var document = Document.FromJson(json);
        document.Remove("Questions");
        var testTable = Table.LoadTable(_client, Tables.Tests.TableName);
        var put = GeneratePutAsync(document, testTable, Tables.Tests.Fields.Id);
        transactionActions.Add(new TransactWriteItem { Put = put });

        //save items then
        if (testDto.Questions != null && testDto.Questions.Any())
        {
            //save questions
            var questionsTable = Table.LoadTable(_client, Tables.Questions.TableName);
            foreach (var question in testDto.Questions)
            {
                json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(question);
                document = Document.FromJson(json);
                document.Remove("Answers");
                document.Remove("Images");
                put = GeneratePutAsync(document, questionsTable, Tables.Questions.Fields.Id);
                transactionActions.Add(new TransactWriteItem { Put = put });

                if (question.Answers != null && question.Answers.Any())
                {
                    var answersTable = Table.LoadTable(_client, Tables.Answers.TableName);
                    foreach (var answer in question.Answers)
                    {
                        json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(answer);
                        document = Document.FromJson(json);
                        put = GeneratePutAsync(document, answersTable, Tables.Answers.Fields.Id);
                        transactionActions.Add(new TransactWriteItem { Put = put });
                    }
                }

                if (question.Images != null && question.Images.Any())
                {
                    var imagesTable = Table.LoadTable(_client, Tables.Images.TableName);
                    foreach (var image in question.Images)
                    {
                        json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(image);
                        document = Document.FromJson(json);
                        put = GeneratePutAsync(document, imagesTable, Tables.Images.Fields.Id);
                        transactionActions.Add(new TransactWriteItem { Put = put });
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        var transactionResult = await RunTransaction(transactionActions);

        return Result.OK;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return Result.KO;
    }
}
```

`RunTransactions`:

```
private async Task<int> RunTransaction(List<TransactWriteItem> actions)
{
    var transaction = new TransactWriteItemsRequest()
    {
        TransactItems = actions,
        ReturnConsumedCapacity = ReturnConsumedCapacity.TOTAL
    };

    // Run the transaction and process the result.
    try
    {
        var transactionResult = await _client.TransactWriteItemsAsync(transaction);
        Console.WriteLine("Transaction Successful");
        return Result.OK;
    }
    catch (ResourceNotFoundException rnf)
    {
        Console.Error.WriteLine("One of the table involved in the transaction is not found" + rnf.Message);
        return Result.KO;
    }
    catch (InternalServerErrorException ise)
    {
        Console.Error.WriteLine("Internal Server Error" + ise.Message);
        return Result.KO;
    }
    catch (TransactionCanceledException tce)
    {
        Console.Error.WriteLine("Transaction Canceled " + tce.Message);
        return Result.KO;
    }
    catch (Exception tce)
    {
        Console.Error.WriteLine("General error: " + tce.Message);
        return Result.KO;
    }
}
```

It's true that I am including multiple operations in the same element (in my case Delete + Put), but I have to. Besides, they're **different** operations.

I checked this [Transaction request cannot include multiple operations on one item python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65231031/transaction-request-cannot-include-multiple-operations-on-one-item-python), but it doesn't include a solution.

I know the best would be to do updates instead of delete + insert, the problem  is that way I would need to check for every question, answer and image if I'm updating or inserting, and this could make my code more complex.

Any solution to this?

### Edit 1

Even I've already answered my own question I'm editing because I just wanted to let the reason why I was deleting items first very clear to help other developers.

If a user is editing a test and deletes one or more questions, then I obviously have to delete that particular question(s) (the same for answers and images), what forces me to keep track of deleted questions and answers from the view (I use Javascript), what in the end makes the code much more complex.

Apparently you cannot do edit and put operations in the same items together in the same transaction, so I'll have to use only put and delete items when necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing deeper research I've found that a "PutItem" operation can also do an update (if the partition key already exists). In the end that means that without modifying code I can skip initial "Delete" operations and just do "Put" ones to accomplish a working transaction.

Working solution:

```
public async Task<int> CreateTestAsync(TestDTO testDto)
{
    if (testDto.Questions == null) return Result.KO;

    try
    {
        //save test data
        transactionActions = new List<TransactWriteItem>();

        //save test
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(testDto);
        var document = Document.FromJson(json);
        document.Remove("Questions");
        var testTable = Table.LoadTable(_client, Tables.Tests.TableName);
        var put = GeneratePutAsync(document, testTable, Tables.Tests.Fields.Id);
        transactionActions.Add(new TransactWriteItem { Put = put });

        //save items then
        if (testDto.Questions != null && testDto.Questions.Any())
        {
            //save questions
            var questionsTable = Table.LoadTable(_client, Tables.Questions.TableName);
            foreach (var question in testDto.Questions)
            {
                json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(question);
                document = Document.FromJson(json);
                document.Remove("Answers");
                document.Remove("Images");
                    
                put = GeneratePutAsync(document, questionsTable, Tables.Questions.Fields.Id);

                transactionActions.Add(new TransactWriteItem { Put = put });

                if (question.Answers != null && question.Answers.Any())
                {
                    var answersTable = Table.LoadTable(_client, Tables.Answers.TableName);
                    foreach (var answer in question.Answers)
                    {
                        json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(answer);
                        document = Document.FromJson(json);
                        put = GeneratePutAsync(document, answersTable, Tables.Answers.Fields.Id);
                        transactionActions.Add(new TransactWriteItem { Put = put });
                    }
                }

                if (question.Images != null && question.Images.Any())
                {
                    var imagesTable = Table.LoadTable(_client, Tables.Images.TableName);
                    foreach (var image in question.Images)
                    {
                        json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(image);
                        document = Document.FromJson(json);
                        put = GeneratePutAsync(document, imagesTable, Tables.Images.Fields.Id);
                        transactionActions.Add(new TransactWriteItem { Put = put });
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        var transactionResult = await RunTransaction(transactionActions);

        return Result.OK;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return Result.KO;
    }
}
```

The "RunTransaction" method keeps intact as it can be seen in the original question.